# Django with Cloud SQL on GAE Flexible

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

My Django app is working on GAE with Cloud SQL（MySQL）.

By using New Relic Monitoring, I tracked requests done by my app to www.googleapis.com.

I don't know those requests. Can somebody explain this behavior?

[image]

(app connecting with cloud proxy)

Comment: >Do you mean that why your app is making these requests.
yes. I do not make request to googleapis.com. just cloud sql only.

Answer (score 0):

As merely described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed), there are various processes running in the instance along side (with?) your application... scaling, billing, logging, etc. Communication with other Google Cloud Services (like the ones I previously mentioned) is mainly done through Google Cloud [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/apis/). Since App Engine is a *managed* Platform as a Service, this management needs to be done somehow... a myriad of [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/overview#multiple-surfaces-rest-and-grpc) requests and responses do this. Partly through the www.googleapis.com endpoint.

You don't have to worry, though... your application's performance is not affected by this, nor your billing account.